# For which primes p is $p^2+2^p$ also prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

for 3: $3^2+2^3=17$

so 3 is the only solution?

thanks!

Comment: Show your works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $p=6m\pm1$

$$p^2+2^p\equiv(\pm1)^2+(-1)^{6m\pm1}\equiv0\pmod3$$

Comment: nice analysis...

Comment: it's also possible to show it's the sum of three squares.